# iterator.next skipping index

Tags: java, iterator, apache-poi

I have an iterator and the values are like this:

```
index   value
0        A
1        B
2        null
3        null
4        E
5        F
```

and here is my code:

```
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
      cell = cellIterator.next();
      System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
}
```

and the output is

```
A
B
E
F
```

Why does it skip indexes when the value is null?
How can I loop over all indexes although the value is null?
I want the output to be like:

```
A
B
null
null
E
F
```

Comment: What's the type of `row`?

Comment: Is this Apache POI code, with `Row`s and `Cell`s?

Comment: from where you are getting value set ?

Comment: @Eran it's Row from org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row

Comment: @rgettman yes, it's from Apache POI

Comment: @PavanKumarReddyMarri I read from excel with Apache POI

Comment: This link might help you [link](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `null` values aren't showing up because in Excel, the `Cell`s don't exist in cells 2 and 3.  There are only 4 cells total in that row.

If you want to cover the entire row, even where there aren't cells, you must change from using an iterator to a traditional for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++)
{
    cell = row.getCell(i);
    if (cell == null)
    {
        System.out.println("null");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    }
}
```

The [`getLastCellNum` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getLastCellNum()) "Gets the index of the last cell contained in this row **PLUS ONE**.", so the `for` loop condition is correct as written.

I had code using the [`MissingCellPolicy` `CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK), which will turn a nonexistent `Cell` into a blank `Cell`, which results in `""`, so we must test whether the cell is present with a null check.

> A new, blank cell is created for missing cells. Blank cells are returned as normal